# SystemError on cropping image by bounding box

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I have this code below, it works on some images for cropping sub-images for every word in the image contains text. Some images raised an issue while cropping them, I could not find the reason and solution for the error, please help.
**the error:**

```
SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

**the code:**

```
IMAGE_PATH = '005002006002-1.tiff'
conv = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
reader = easyocr.Reader(['ar'],gpu=True)
result = reader.readtext(conv)

img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
Image_number = 1000
copy = img.copy()
for i in result:
    top_left = tuple([int(val) for val in i[0][0]])
    bottom_right = tuple([int(val) for val in i[0][2]])
    img = cv2.rectangle(copy, top_left, bottom_right, (36,255,12), 3)
    cropped_img = img[top_left[1]:bottom_right[1], top_left[0]:bottom_right[0], :] 
    plt.imsave('newsub/005002006002-1_{}.tiff'.format(Image_number), cropped_img )
    Image_number += 1
```

Comment: can you link a download for your image?

Comment: thanks Synthase , it is Arabic handwritten scanned document

Comment: Yes sure, but I'd need to have your image file to reproduce the error.

Comment: sure, I will upload it now

Comment: The error states * tile cannot extend outside image*, which means you are trying to crop a region beyond the dimension of the image. Check whether the text file contains the correct coordinates. You might be confused with the coordinate system of images (I think).

Comment: I cannot upload it says "Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MiB)." how can send it to u? thanks

Comment: Thanks Shradha, I tried to change the coordinates but issue still appears .

Comment: Try replece img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH) by img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

Comment: Thanks Alex, I did what you mentioned, unfortunately same issue